# Why can you call a method before it has been defined?

Tags: java, compilation

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        anotherTest();
        test();
    }
    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("Printed from the test method.");
    }
    public static void anotherTest() {
        System.out.println("Printed from the anotherTest method.");
    }
}
```

I would like to know why you can call a method before it has been defined like the code above. The code above shows two methods at the bottom of the page but I am calling them in the main method before they have been loaded. If I were to do something similar in Python I would get an error.

Comment: Because compilation and execution are distinct steps.

Comment: And Java is not Python. There are different language rules.

Comment: Like other languages, there is a hierarchy of steps which must be followed by every program. Static methods/variables are loaded at runtime

Comment: @Ksai If static methods are loaded at runtime then that means the main method would be loaded first. If the main method is loaded first wouldn't everything inside that be executed without the other static methods being loaded?

Comment: @Test `main` method is not executed because it's static, it executes because it is the [Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) for any java program. To call any method you can simply call from main

Comment: This is actually a perfectly good question (though I suspect that there must be a very good answer already somewhere here on Stack Overflow). In short: Java is a compiled language, so the entire source code is compiled (analysed and converted into a lower-level executable code) before it can be executed. So by the time execution occurs, the compiler has generated a map of the entire set of classes, methods, etc, and knows where to find any valid method which is called, regardless of the order of the code. Python, on the other hand, is an "interpreted language", and reads from start to finish.

Comment: @Bobulous there are also compiled languages (e.g. Pascal) that do not allow to use things before they are defined.

Comment: And actually no, in Python that would not be an error either.

Comment: @LewBloch In python, you would get an error if you tried to call a method before it has been defined.

Comment: Inside a Python (3) class, you can refer to a method defined later in the class. You are wrong, @Test. I do it all the time. I did it just yesterday. So yes, you can have a forward reference to a method in Python. I have the code that proves it. Sounds like you need to review Python's documentation.

Comment: @LewBloch I wasn't referring to OO Python. I was referring to procedural Python.

Comment: We can only respond to what you actually said. Whatever you might mean by "procedural Python", the Java example you have here is a forward reference within a class. Why would anyone not compare that to the same idiom in Python? Forward reference in a class on the left, forward reference in a class on the right. Let's compare equivalent situations, shall we?

Answer (score -1):

That's because Python gets compiled on the run, while in java the compiler handles this problem (it search for the declarations in the whole code)